# Full target/current URL in play framework?

Tags: java, url, path, playframework

Any ideas how to get the current URL with the play framework?
I'm also looking for the full target URL. I know I can use `@{Controller.method}` but I need the full url (for the Facebook like button)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An absolute path is created using `@@`

So, you would use

```
@@{Controller.method}
```

However, to get the current path, without specifying a specific controller and action, you can use

```
${request.url}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Play 2.0, it's

```
@request.path
```

(more info [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.3/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestHeader.html#path%28%29))